# White line appearing on border in react-native

Tags: ios, css, react-native, flexbox

I am using three `TouchableOpacity` instances laid out in a row as follows:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RTCView streamURL={this.state.remoteURL} style={styles.video1} />
      <RTCView streamURL={this.state.videoURL} style={styles.video2} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.start}>
        <Text> Start </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.call}>
        <Text> Call </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.receive}>
        <Text> Receive </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>

const styles = {
  // leaving out video1 and video2
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 0.3,
    height: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000'
  },
  button: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: '#000',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD'
  }
};
```

However, one of the borders of the button has a white line running across it (visible between the Call and Receive button).

[image]

The problem occurs on iOS only for both the simulator and the actual device. It looks fine for Android.

I've tried different values for `justifyContent` but the behavior still persists. The white line occurs for different borderWidth values (even for 1). The closest thing I can find is this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2089) but it deals with `borderRadius`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have this problem with react-native 0.50.4, iOS 7 plus / iOS 8 plus simulator.

Comment: Giving `flex: 1` to the buttons makes them all the same width (123.5pt) on iPhone 6s. From here it is simple math 123.5*3 + 2 + 2 = 374.5; Somewhere the 0.5pt must be filled. (375pt total) And with what? With nothing! :D All-In-All: make the `backgroundColor` of the `buttonContainer` black and everything is fine for now. If you want to clean up the code a little bit after that: replace the `borderWidth` with `margin` in the `button` styles, so you have to change the color just in 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later but I experienced a similar issue and found the solution so I figured I'd share for anyone else experiencing this issue.

In your scenario, you've reported encountering a visual issue where a white line appears on the border in your React Native application. While the original question pertains to the use of TouchableOpacity, I've encountered a similar problem while utilizing the Tab component from react-navigation.

The issue you're facing is that `borderTopWidth` is assigned a value of `0.3333333333333333` on iOS, which I found after using the Element Inspector. To remove the line set `borderTopWidth: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import { Platform } from 'react-native';

 buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 0.3,
    height: 5, // Adjust this as needed
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'transparent' : '#000', // Change styling for iOS
```

},